# SwiftUI GeometryReader causes memory leak

Tags: swiftui

Consider the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
//        self.sample
        GeometryReader { _ in
            self.sample
        }
    }

    var sample: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct Tabs : View {
    @State var selection: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            TestView().tabItem {
                Text("First Tab")
            }
            .tag(0)

            Text(String(selection))
            .tabItem {
                Text("Second Tab")
            }
            .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

There are two tabs and selection is referenced in body therefore body will be called when selection is changed.
TestView is using GeometryReader.
When I switch from "First Tab" to "Second Tab" ViewModel is created again and never dereferenced. This is unexpected.
If I switch 100 times I will have 100 ViewModels referenced from SwiftUI internals.

Though if i remove GeometryReader it works as expected.

Did someone experience it? Are there any workarounds?
I simply want this ViewModel lifetime to be bound to TestView lifetime.

UPDATE:

XCode 11.3.1 iOS 13.3

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let's make the following changes in `ViewModel`

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        print(">> inited") // you can put breakpoint here in Debug Preview
    }
}
```

so now it seen that because View is value type

```
struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel() // << new instance on each creation
    ...
```

and it is originated from

```
var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        TestView().tabItem { // << created on each tab switch
        ...
```

so, the solution would be to `ViewModel` creation out of `TestView` and inject outer instance either via `.environmentObject` or via constructor arguments.

Btw, it does not depend on `GeometryReader`. Tested with Xcode 11.2.1 / iOS 13.2